# Prettier format code write by me, not the whole team

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am a programmer, and I started using prettier,
I want prettier to format the code write only by me, for example if I open a JavaScript file pushed on Git by other members of the team, I dont want that code to be formated. Is there any posibility?

Searched on the web but nothing found

Comment: Welcome! It's unclear exactly what you're asking, but it seems related to managing your build pipelines. You should probably talk to your team about this as well, regarding formatting standards, tools used in the build pipeline, etc. Unfortunately this isn't a question for Stack Overflow (at least, as written).

Comment: How will you know which code was written by you?  You could search all your source files and select only those with `Author: aleonor nyikita` in a comment at the top of the file or something.  Or you could harvest the git log and only format lines blamed to you.  Or you could curate your own list of files in your .prettierignore file which permits the `!` syntax to negate ignore rules (explicitly include files).

Comment: Check my answer below - Visual Studio Code *does* know to format just your changes. @Wyck You might be interested as well.

Answer (score 3):

### Setting: Format On Save Mode

Visual Studio Code has a setting "Format On Save Mode", which you can set to "modifications", which will only format the changes you made.
You might need some experimentation with this feature but it promises exactly what you are asking.

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for *format*
3. Find *Editor: Format On Save Mode*
4. Change value to *modifications*
5. Evaluate the other auto-formatting options if they make sense to deactivate

See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: I've tried this and it still formats from the selection and below, which is weird. Care to share your prettier config?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have web projects anymore, the config is at my previous company. This isn't about a selection, it is about changes made in the file (which might require code management like Git). Formatting a selection is `Ctrl+K`, `Ctrl+F`.

Comment: oh yeah you're right, now when I tried format on save it still formats the whole file lol

Comment: Have you set the value to "modifications" as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: weird, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: I can also confirm that `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable"` and `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications"` don't always work as expected. In one case what seemed to be the problem for me is that I had a global `.prettierrc` file with one or two rules - and those were applied even to non-modified ranges of files I'm editing. I'd understand that it would override rules from a project level file depending on the naming (https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html), but it still doesn't explain why VSCode is formatting ranges that I haven't touched.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for that, but you can ignore the code you don't want to format with specific comments.

e.g. to ignore js code you need to type // prettier-ignore

```
// prettier-ignore
matrix(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)
```

You can check their documentation to learn more: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: There *is* an option for that. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for me only format on type enabling worked. complete configurations -

```
{
    "scm.alwaysShowActions": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": ["rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"],
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "all",
    "window.zoomLevel": -2,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": false,
        "source.fixAll.eslint": false
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
    },
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false, // required
    "editor.formatOnType": true, // optional
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications", // required to format on save
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange", // optional but recommended
    "vs-code-prettier-eslint.prettierLast": "false" // set as "true" to run 'prettier' last not first
}
```